# Declaring correctly variables in c

Tags: c, scanf

What is following will surely appear very simple for c coders but I am coding a small program to modelize some game called gomoku. For the user, you have to enter an integer N wich corresponds to a 'N times N' square which consists of 'N times N' integers.

So the code is runnig quite well but I have some simple question : when I enter the 'N times N' integers, I made some

```
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    char c[N][N];
    while (i<N){
        scanf("%s\n",&c[i]); 
        i++;
    }
```

then I converted the char to int for each `c[i]` to make some computation involving `c[i][j]`, which is quite unnatural. But if I had to declare int `c[N][N]`, it would be impossible to retrive the same integers `c[i][j]` like those I inputed when the while-loop is running.

Does anyone has an idea to declare int `c[N][N]`, inputing integers, and then computing the same when computing with integers `c[i][j]` ?

Best, 
Newben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to read char and then convert it to int. You can just simply read integeres:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    scanf("%d", &c[i]);       //of course c has to be int** type
```

And are you sure that you want to read just N integers? Not N*N for whole array? In case you want to read N*N objects to array, code should look like this:

```
int N, i, j;
scanf("%d",&N);
int c[N][N];

for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        scanf("%d", &c[i][j]);
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see, I wanted to avoid nested loops but thanks a lot for this very complete response

Comment: Firstly, he *doesn't* have to use dynamic allocation. Modern C language supports variable-length arrays that can be declared as in the original code. Secondly, even if you decide to use dynamic allocation, please, avoid the bizarre practice of casting the result of `malloc`.

Comment: "Modern C" but who said that he use the latest compilator? There is nothing wrong about it and i have sure that it'll work for everyone who read this topic, independet of their compilators. About these castings, of course they are unnecessary. My fault.

Comment: @Blood: Well, "modern C" is C99 actually, 99 being a reference to 1999. There's no need for "the latest compiler". And judging by the original post (*"...the code is running quite well..."*), the OP apparently had no problem compiling the `char c[N][N]` declaration, meaning that OP's compiler does support VLAs.

Comment: @Blood "modern" is already 13 years old. You don't need nearly the latest compilers.

Comment: In fact, I tried to avoid nested loops because I must jump to the line. Is there any quick maner to declare my variables knowing I have to jump to the lie each time N integers are entered ?

Comment: @Newben: The input method from Blood's code is correct. As for the the allocation method, you don't need to do all that `malloc/free` stuff at all. Just keep your `char c[N][N]`.

Comment: Okey i have edited my post. That's true what you tell guys, so i'm sorry for my bad :( Now i'm just curious why everybody told me that i have to use dynamic allocation ...

Comment: @Blood : the code you edited doesn't work in my situation because it doesn't care about jumping to the line each time N integers are entered

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want it to jump? Which line?

Comment: In fact, you have N^2 integers that forme a square of N lines. There is no space between each integer on each line, however you want to treat each integer like separate entities to compute with them, so you need to grab c[i][j]'s, (that's the reason why I precedently used char c[N][N])