# Using scanf() to input a square of integers

Tags: c, scanf

I am coding a c project, that needs that the user enters a N*N square of integers : that's to say an input of N lines of N integers. The algo works fine.

Now I want the user to input N lines of N integers each of consecutive integers are separated by a space. Here, I don't have the right usage of scanf, because I tried to declare integers array but I was not able to deal with the spacing.

I tried something like this, very unnatural and failing :

```
int i=0;
int j=0;

int N;
scanf("%d",&N);

char c[N][2*N-1];

while(i < N){
    scanf("%s",&c[i]);
    i++;
}

i=0;
j=0;
while (i<N){
    while (j<N){
        c[i][j]=c[i][2*j]-48;
        j++;
    }
    j=0;
    i++;
}
```

Can someone help ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: If you need a "square", why is your array declared as a "rectangle"? Where did `2*N-1` as the second dimension come from?

Comment: Style is important. In future, please try to keep it tidier.

Comment: Because at the n-th input, the user jumps to line so press the enter key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring correctly variables in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352140/declaring-correctly-variables-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what your original code was supposed to do then this code should actually do it (and print it out again just to prove it worked).

You need to dynamically allocate the array since it's variable size ( In C99 you could use variable sized arrays on the stack but that's really a different discussion ).

scanf will automatically ignore white-space between the integers (including spaces and new-lines) so you don't need to parse that out manually.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, N;
    int **c;

    scanf("%d",&N);

    c = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        c[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(c[i]);
    }
    free(c);
    return 0;
 }
```

C99 alternative without malloc/free for completeness (I'v never liked this C99 feature since there's no way to check that the was/is enough space on the stack):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, N;

    scanf("%d",&N);

    int c[N][N];

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Newben What C compiler doesn't support `malloc()` and `free()`? Are you doing `#include stdlib.h>` What happens or how do you know it doesn't support these two functions?

Comment: Oups, perhaps malloc and free are recognized, in fact the error is an undefined variable c

Comment: So I am not familiar to this way of working with a variable. How should I declare c ?

Comment: OK sorry fixed that. Tidied it up a little too much before I pasted it in.

Comment: I'm honestly not trying to be in any way offensive, but if you not familiar with dynamic memory allocation or pointers you should read a book on programming in C before you post here again.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, it works ! Could you explain quickly how this is magically working :)

Comment: The same error as in the previous "iteration"... Why is everyone trying to force him to use dynamic allocation? In C language there's no need to dynamically allocate run-time sized arrays anymore. C language supports run-time sized arrays since C99. There are reasons to use `malloc`/`free` in many cases, but this is obviously not one of them. Don't overcomplicate things.